# Passing Parameter Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

At the First Page, I got the List View and Event Handler Items Tapped, When I passing the data to second page the Constructor display Error.

**First Page**

```
 private async void friendlistProfile_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var user = e.Item as User;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new FriendsDetails(user));

    }
```

**Second Page**

```
 public FriendsDetails(User user)
        {
            this.user = user;
        }
```

**The Error Display in SecondPage**
[Error in Second Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT1Y6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `User` to be public:

```
public class Branch {

}
```